# JHipster test: NoCacheRegionFactoryAvailableException when second level cache is disabled

Tags: gradle, junit, ehcache, jhipster

When I use jhipster generate an app, I disabled the second level cache. However, when I run either "gradle test" or "run as junit test" to test the app, it is failed because the "NoCacheRegionFactoryAvailableException". I have checked the application.yml in directory "src/test/resources/config", and be sure that the second cache is disabled. I do not know why the app is still looking for second-cache. Is there any clue how this happen? or how to disable second level cache completely?

Except the test failure, everything else works well, the app can run successfully.

application.yml in src/test/resources/config

```yaml
spring:
    application:
        name: EMS
    datasource:
        url: jdbc:h2:mem:EMS;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1
        name:
        username:
        password:
    jpa:
        database-platform: com.espion.ems.domain.util.FixedH2Dialect
        database: H2
        open-in-view: false
        show_sql: true
        hibernate:
            ddl-auto: none
            naming-strategy: org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.hibernate.SpringNamingStrategy
        properties:
            hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache: false
            hibernate.cache.use_query_cache: false
            hibernate.generate_statistics: true
            hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto: validate
    data:
        elasticsearch:
            cluster-name:
            cluster-nodes:
            properties:
                path:
                  logs: target/elasticsearch/log
                  data: target/elasticsearch/data
    mail:
        host: localhost
    mvc:
        favicon:
            enabled: false
    thymeleaf:
        mode: XHTML
liquibase:
    contexts: test

security:
    basic:
        enabled: false

server:
    port: 10344
    address: localhost

jhipster:
    async:
        corePoolSize: 2
        maxPoolSize: 50
        queueCapacity: 10000
    security:
        rememberMe:
            # security key (this key should be unique for your application, and kept secret)
            key: jhfasdhflasdhfasdkfhasdjkf
    metrics: # DropWizard Metrics configuration, used by MetricsConfiguration
        jmx.enabled: true
    swagger:
        title: EMS API
        description: EMS API documentation
        version: 0.0.1
        termsOfServiceUrl:
        contactName:
        contactUrl:
        contactEmail:
        license:
        licenseUrl:
        enabled: false
```

Answer (score -1):

Move `src/test/resources/config/application.yml` to `src/test/resources` directory.

You can find that solution from https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/issues/3730